# ExtJs 6.2 Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extjs, extjs6-modern

I got this error inside `ExtJS` Modern toolkit and I am not able to fix the issue.
the error says:

> Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080

How to fix this issue. I Know how to get it working but when I build the `Sencha` app, it rewrite my code. How to solve the issue?
below is the function of the `ext-modern-all.js` file causing the issue:

```
preventDefault: function() {
    var me = this,
        parentEvent = me.parentEvent;
    me.defaultPrevented = true;


    if (parentEvent) {
        parentEvent.defaultPrevented = true;
    }
    me.browserEvent.preventDefault();// This the error line
    return me;
},
```

Comment: which version of chrome you are using?

Comment: Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: I have same version but in my browser I am not getting any issue regarding for same. Can you provide some fiddle or some exact senario how you getting this error?.